# How does Xen expose hardware to guests?

Tags: virtualization, xen, hypervisor

(*I feel this question half belongs here and half on Server Fault; please let me know if you think there's a better venue for it.*)

How does Xen, or indeed, any hypervisor, expose hardware to guest operating systems?

For instance, a guest wanting to communicate on the network; at some stage its request must get translated into a request to the NIC. Does the hypervisor expose a dummy network device, which we assume the guest knows how to use? Or do paravirtualised guests have knowledge of how to directly make a request for a given piece of hardware? (If so, what do non-paravirtualised guests do?)

Once the request is made, who handles it? I'm guessing the hypervisor has no little knowledge about physical hardware (from a driver perspective), so it probably has to come down to the dom0. Right?

I ask because I love doing kernel development, but writing drivers is a chore. If I could rely on a dom0 with pretty good hardware support (Ubuntu, say), and then just write my kernel to run paravirtualised, and/or to make use of some mock device that Xen exposes, that would make my life a lot easier. It's pretty difficult to find documentation on these topics, however, so my next stop is probably to look at a range of Xen guest implementations; [HaLVM](http://halvm.org/wiki/), a port of GHC for running Haskell software natively as a Xen guest, looks like a good start.

Thanks and salutations!

**Edit**: [this marketing doc from Xen.org](http://www.xen.org/files/Marketing/HowDoesXenWork.pdf) seems to state that the dom0 runs drivers in order to facilitate domUs' block device and network access, in line with my guess. In this case, any technical references/specs/etc. would be awesome!

**Edit**: [this (apparently outdated) documentation](http://wiki.xensource.com/xenwiki/XenNetworking) looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three types of device models.

1. PV — For example, Linux PV guests use pv_ops (http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/XenParavirtOps, http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Category:PVOPS)
2. HVM — full virtualization of devices with QEMU (https://serverfault.com/questions/222010/difference-between-xen-pv-xen-kvm-and-hvm)
3. Passthrough (http://wiki.xensource.com/wiki/Xen_PCI_Passthrough)

The book [The Definitive Guide to the Xen Hypervisor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013234971X) might be useful to you.

There is quite a bit of development related info on the wiki:
http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Category:Developers.

Comment: Thank you—this is awesome. And your credentials certainly make me feel at ease. :)